# Is there a more effective way to compare multiple values between two tables than using multiple “AND” statements in the where clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables –

Table one is Employees -- contains an employee record with an id, active status and organizational level value (workgroup).

```
WG1 = company
WG2 = department
WG3 = cost center
WG4 = floor
WG5 = shift
WG6 = role
```

An employee will only have one record and will always have a value in each field (nulls are not allowed)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EMPLOYEES](
[EmpID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ACTIVESTATUS] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG1] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG2] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG3] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG4] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG5] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG6] [smallint] NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EMPLOYEES]
    ([FILEKEY],[ACTIVESTATUS],[WG1],[WG2],[WG3],[WG4],[WG5],[WG6])
VALUES
    (193,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Table two is Useraccess which is a user table.  This table represents the organizational access a user has so there can be multiple records.  All fields will have a value however 0 represents all.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USERACCESS](
[USERID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[WG1] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG2] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG3] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG4] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG5] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[WG6] [smallint] NOT NULL)
    

INSERT INTO [dbo].[USERACCESS]
       ([USERID],[WG1],[WG2],[WG3],[WG4],[WG5],[WG6])
VALUES
       (1927,0,0,0,1,0,0),
       (1927,1,1,1,0,1,2)
```

1927,0,0,0,1,0,0 = access to all employees with shift (WG5) = 1
1927,1,1,1,0,1,2 = Company 1, Department 1, Cost Center 1, All Floors, Shift 1, Role 2

This user would have access to the sample employee based on the first user access record.

Right now in order to determine if a user had access to a specific employee a script like the following would be used with a comparison with each WG value compared individually as well as checking to see if the value was 0.

```
SELECT 0
,count(*)
FROM employees e
WHERE (e.activestatus = 0)
AND (
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM USERACCESS U
        WHERE (U.USERID = 1927)
            AND (
                (
                    (U.WG1 = E.WG1)
                    OR (U.WG1 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG2 = E.WG2)
                    OR (U.WG2 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG3 = E.WG3)
                    OR (U.WG3 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG4 = E.WG4)
                    OR (U.WG4 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG5 = E.WG5)
                    OR (U.WG5 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG6 = E.WG6)
                    OR (U.WG6 = 0)
                    )
                )
        ) > 0
    )
UNION
SELECT 1
,count(*)
FROM employees e
WHERE (e.activestatus = 1)
AND (
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM USERACCESS U
        WHERE (U.USERID = 1927)
            AND (
                (
                    (U.WG1 = E.WG1)
                    OR (U.WG1 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG2 = E.WG2)
                    OR (U.WG2 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG3 = E.WG3)
                    OR (U.WG3 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG4 = E.WG4)
                    OR (U.WG4 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG5 = E.WG5)
                    OR (U.WG5 = 0)
                    )
                AND (
                    (U.WG6 = E.WG6)
                    OR (U.WG6 = 0)
                    )
                )
        ) > 0
    )
ORDER BY 1
```

This type of query is one of the most frequently executed and as such has some of the highest number of reads as it reads the entire employees table multiple times so I am looking for a query which might do this more effectively.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: Thank you for the input, I hope my changes made improved my presentation.

Comment: the pattern (select Count(*) ...) > 0 should almost always be replaced by EXISTS

Comment: Please read the guidelines on the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I replaced the count(*) with an exists and while it seems cleaner I am not seeing any difference in overall performance but thank you for the advice, I will be making that change in future versions of this code.